# Run VHDL code that displays on monitor

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am new to VHDL and FPGA. I have a Cyclone 2, DE 1 board. I am trying to program in VHDL such that it produces an animation of something (Say an algorithm). I have worked on the board and played with switches. Now, the biggest challenge for me is to get the display. For simple programs, I load the .sof file and directly manipulate the switches. Now, I downloaded a VHDL code that draws a rectangle to understand VGA and compiled it. When I load the .sof files, it loads but I do not see anything on the screen. My question is, Should VGA involved files be loaded/run in any different manner? I see that lots of material is available for xilinx but not for cyclone 2. Can anyone help me as to how the VGA works with respect to coding, compiling and running? I know the theory, need some basic practical knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to write a VGA driver. I learned it on [this site](http://eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15925278). The example is pretty suitable for one who isn't familiar with VGA. You can download example code as well. Pay attention to the timing specifications for various VGA modes at the bottom of that page.

Also [this](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&ved=0CF0QFjAI&url=http://ece.gmu.edu/coursewebpages/ECE/ECE448/S13/viewgraphs/ECE448_lecture7_VGA_1.pdf&ei=pPdUUv6_K-6uiQev9oCIBg&usg=AFQjCNFNA2xSJ0JLjYf0e483VnzMdc9QNQ&sig2=1NjssiMhVWCNWJUhQgWa7w) teaches how to write a Pong game. Have fun with it:).

Comment: The sites give ample amount of information and they are very clear. Thanks for that. I had one small doubt. When I write the VHDL code, for VGA, do I still need to assign pins manually? or they are taken care of? Lastly, I am assuming that I just have to load .sof file.

Comment: @San If your board has a VGA connector, you just need to output to that and connect your board to a monitor using a VGA cable. Before this, you should read the schematic of your FPGA board carefully to make sure that you output to right pins.

Comment: The tutorial is awesome!